# NSNumber storing objects of NSDictionary in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary, nsnumber

My iOS app terminates with `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error. The strange thing is, when I hover the cursor over the NSNumber object (where the error has occurred), it displays the objects of an NSDictionary with Key/Value pair. Following is my code snippet:

```
for(id obj in [MainDict allKeys])
{
    NSArray *AnArrayInsideMainDict = [MainDict objectForKey:obj];
    double i=1;
    for(NSUInteger n=0; n<4; n++)
    {
        NSNumber *anObject = [AnArrayInsideMainDict objectAtIndex:n];
        NSNumber *nextObject = [nextDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:i]];
        NSNumber *HereIsTheError = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(powf(([anObject floatValue]-[nextObject floatValue]),2))];
        [ThisIsMutableArray addObject:HereIsTheError];
        i++
    }
}
```

Here, the `MainDict` contains 64 key/value pairs (each key contains an `NSArray` of 5 objects).`nextDict`is an NSDictionary with 4 key/value pairs (***each key contains one `NSNumber` object*** // **EDIT: each key actually contained an NSArray with single NSNumber Object, this was the reason for the error**). After the app termination and hovering the cursor over the `HereIsTheError`, I get following key/value pair:

[image]

The terminating error at the console is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170257a30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18b032fe0 0x189a94538 0x18b039ef4 0x18b036f54 0x18af32d4c 0x1000891a0 0x10008bd74 0x10020d598 0x100579a50 0x100579a10 0x10057eb78 0x18afe10c8 0x18afdece4 0x18af0eda4 0x18c979074 0x1911c9c9c 0x1000906b4 0x189f1d59c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

How can `NSNumber` conation the objects of `NSDictionary`? I use Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004) and Objective-C.

Comment: What is **powf** ?

Comment: The error message clearly says that `anObject` is `NSMutableArray` not `NSNumber`

Comment: Use of camel casing is encouraged.

Comment: `anObject` or `nextObject` is a `NSMutableArray` object, not a `NSNumber` one. That's what is saying the error.

Comment: @Larme Thanks, I figured out the error. Actually, the values of `nextDict` are NSArrays with single NSNumber objects.

Comment: but to avoid such situations you can check for the function [object isKindOf:ClassName] this could avoid if you are not confirmed about the type of the object.

Comment: @Nitish `powf` is used to compute power of a variable. It's declaration is given as: float powf(float, float);

Comment: Just a suggestion: Using a `double` value (wrapped as an `NSNumber`) is not wise, keys are tested for *equality* and that may not give the results you expect when using floating point values. As all you do is start at `1` and increment use an  integer type for `i`.

Comment: When you declare an object variable in obj-c, it's essentially just an id type, i.e. it can hold *any* objective-c object, be it NSNumber NSDictionary or whatever. If you're unsure what class of object you'll be getting back, it's appropriate to store it into an id variable, until you figure out what it is and can cast it or store it as its specific class. (see @SurbhiGarg comment about isKindOf: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments state, but most importantly your **error message** states, your objects `anObject` and `nextObject` are *not* `NSNumber`'s - they are `NSMutableArray`'s, hence the

> `-[__NSArrayM floatValue]: unrecognized selector...`

part of your error.

Ensure the objects in `AnArrayInsideMainDict` **are in fact** 
`NSNumber`'s before attempting to cast them as numbers,

---

I would suggest flagging your objects before "assuming" their types, but I doubt that would help you get your desired outcome (as this would most likely from your case here skip each object that is **not** an `NSNumber`).

Before you even enter the for loop in `[MainDict allKeys]`, *backtrace* to make sure you are in fact passing arrays of `NSNumber`'s as the dictionaries objects.

---

**IF** you are actually not sure of the object types, you *can* just throw a flag to make sure you are not misinterpreting any of the objects:

```
...

for (NSUInteger n=0; n<4; n++) {

    NSNumber *anObject = [AnArrayInsideMainDict objectAtIndex:n];
    NSNumber *nextObject = [nextDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:i]];

    if ([anObject isKindOfClass:NSNumber.class] && [nextObject isKindOfClass:NSNumber.class]) {

        // Good to continue now that you know the objects

    } else NSLog(@"whoops.. anObject: %@    nextObject: %@", anObject.class, nextObject.class); 

...
```

---

**LASTLY**, if you are so daring, and are sure that somewhere in this dictionary are your `NSNumber`'s, you could flag your steps to check for instances of the `NSNumber.class` in order to seek out your floats.

Otherwise, I suggest deep diving into the **how** and **where** you are getting your `MainDict` from.

Happy coding - cheers!